# How to get time/date string to UTC from local time zone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this string:
"2011-12-05 17:00:00"

where this is local time

```
irb(main):034:0> Time.zone
=> (GMT-08:00) Pacific Time (US & Canada)
```

Now how to I get a Time object with this in UTC?

These don't work:

```
Time.local("2011-12-05 17:00:00") => 2011-01-01 00:00:00 +0000
Time.local("2011-12-05 17:00:00").utc => 2011-01-01 00:00:00 UTC
```

**UPDATE:**

On my local machine, this works:

```
Time.parse("2011-12-05 17:00:00").utc
 => 2011-12-06 01:00:00 UTC
```

but on heroku console it doesn't:

```
Time.parse("2011-12-05 17:00:00").utc
=> 2011-12-05 17:00:00 UTC
```

Answer (score 4):

It seems that you should use `Time.parse` instead of `Time.local`:

```
require "time"
Time.parse("2011-12-05 17:00:00").utc
```

Comment: I added an update to my original post, with the results of that.

Comment: @99miles I think your timezone on heroku is not correctly set. Try `heroku config:add TZ=PST`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in rails application:

```
Time.zone = "Pacific Time"             # => "Pacific Time"
Time.zone.parse("2011-12-05 17:00:00") # => Mon, 05 Dec 2011 17:00:00 UTC +00:00
```

Details [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html#method-i-parse)

Answer (score 0):

I realized my issue was a little more complicated. I wanted to store the times in the database with no time zone, and no time zone conversions. So I left the server and rails app time zone at UTC.
But when I pulled the times out, I would sometimes need to compare them with the current time in the time-zone that the user was in. So I needed to get Time.zone.now for the user, but again, I have Time.zone set to UTC so no automatic conversions happened.

My solution was to pull out the stored user time zone and apply it to Time.now to get the users local time like this:

```
class Business < ActiveRecord::Base
  def tz
    TZInfo::Timezone.get(ActiveSupport::TimeZone::MAPPING[self.time_zone])
  end

  def now
    tz.utc_to_local(Time.zone.now)
  end
end
```

So that I could do something like:

```
@client.appointments.confirmed_in_future(current_business.now)
```

-

```
def confirmed_in_future(date_start = Time.zone.now)
  confirmed.where("time >= ?", date_start)
end
```